# ReactJS: How to use EventListener in child component created in parent

Tags: reactjs

I have this problem when i want to make some events with children from map when i have eventlistener. How to use EventListener in child component created in parent?

Try to resize window:

https://codesandbox.io/s/2j2wnyvln

https://2j2wnyvln.codesandbox.io/

Does it correct code?

Comment: what do you want to happen, you need to be a little more clear in your need.

Comment: @jamesemanon i want to hide some elements in menu, when i resize window. if bounding right of element more then right border of window, i want to hide this element

Answer (score 1):

You can pass event listner with props.
Here is [example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz?editors=0010) from [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) (look at `onTemperatureChange` property of `TemperatureInput`):

```js
// Child
class TemperatureInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onTemperatureChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.props.temperature;
    const scale = this.props.scale;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[scale]}:</legend>
        <input value={temperature}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

// Parent
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCelsiusChange = this.handleCelsiusChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFahrenheitChange = this.handleFahrenheitChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: '', scale: 'c'};
  }

  handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature});
  }

  handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
    this.setState({scale: 'f', temperature});
  }

  render() {
    const scale = this.state.scale;
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    const celsius = scale === 'f' ? tryConvert(temperature, toCelsius) : temperature;
    const fahrenheit = scale === 'c' ? tryConvert(temperature, toFahrenheit) : temperature;

    return (
      <div>
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="c"
          temperature={celsius}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} />
        <TemperatureInput
          scale="f"
          temperature={fahrenheit}
          onTemperatureChange={this.handleFahrenheitChange} />
        <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(celsius)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes, it will work, when i change input and recive value back from children. it's easy. what about resize window? if i add EventListener in child component then we receive lagging and freezing

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly and you want to hide certain child elements based on the parents size, one way to do it could be setting a flag inside the state depending on the size of the parent:

```js
handleResize = e => {
  if (this.state.navHidden === false && window.outerWidth > 500) {
    this.setState({ hidden: true })
  } else if (this.state.navHidden === true && window.outerWidth <= 500) {
    this.setState({ hidden: false })
  }
}
```

then, in your render function you could prevent children from being displayed like so:

```js
render(){
    return(
       this.props.navigation.map(n=>{
         !(n.isBig && this.state.navHidden) && <NavigationList key={n.id} title={n.title} target={n.target} href={n.href}/>
       })
    )
}
```

`n.isBig` would be a flag that you set on the nav items to determine if those should be hidden in smaller screen sizes. But you probably have some sort of other measure to determine that.

Since what you are trying to do is display logic, you should also check if the desired behaviour can be done using plain CSS and `media-queries`.

Comment: No. i have 15 elements in menu for example. And if i resize the window i sort out all elements and compare their right boundings with window right boundings. And if boundings of element more then window right boundings then i hide this element. It works, but very slow and freezing, because i have window.addEventListener in every child component